# Pod install displaying error in cocoapods version 1.3.2

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode8

192:podss etcxm$ pod install --verbose

Preparing Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate Using ARCHS setting to build architectures of target Pods-podss: (``)

Resolving dependencies of Podfile

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest A FMDB

Downloading dependencies

-> Installing FMDB (2.6.2)

Copying FMDB from  /Users/etcxm/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/FMDB/2.6.2-854a0 to  Pods/FMDB - Running pre install hooks Generating Pods project - Creating Pods project - Adding source files to Pods project - Adding frameworks to Pods project - Adding libraries to Pods project - Adding resources to Pods project - Linking headers - Installing targets - Installing target FMDB iOS 4.3 - Installing target Pods-podss iOS 8.0 - Running post install hooks - Writing Xcode project file to Pods/Pods.xcodeproj

- Generating deterministic UUIDs

Abort trap: 6

I've tried reinstall cocoa pods, but not succeed.

Answer (score -1):

Look like you're try to install **verbose**

This is what worked for me

```
   1. Delete all the content under ~./CocoaPods
   2. Delete your existing podfile.lock and Pods folder
   3. Leave your PodFile intact
   4. Run 'sudo gem install cocoapods --verbose'
   5. Run 'pod install --verbose'
```